# Need driver for touch screen

Tags: touch, raspberry-pi

I got a 10 inch touch screen for a Raspberry Pi, but the CD along with the touch controller supported only Win CE, Fedora, Suse, Redhat. I tried Suse and Fedora; the files were in script format, `.sh`.

I tried `chmod +x`, then `sh touchkit.setup_Suse90.sh`, and I got this error:

For Suse:

```
sh touchkit.setup_suse90.sh 
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 2: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: //
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 3: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: ://
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 4: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: ://
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 6: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: ://
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 8: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: ://
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 9: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: ://
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 10: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: ://
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 11: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: ://
: not foundtup_suse90.sh: 16: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: //
touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: 1: touchkit.setup_suse90.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")//
```

For Fedora:

```
bash: ./touchkit.setup_fdr.sh: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory//
```

But I need it for Wheezy… what should I do?

Comment: Try [RaspberryPi.SE], [Unix.SE], [Ubuntu.SE], or [SU] instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These files are broken due to end-of-line conversion from the UNIX format (LF) to the DOS format (CRLF). One common cause of such corruption is FTP transfer in ASCII mode instead of binary.

However, if these drivers are the same as available at http://www.touchkit.com/Drivers.htm, they are ancient and useless for modern Linux versions; some drivers also contain x86-only binary parts without sources, and licensing is unclear. Don't waste time with them — instead, attach the touchscreen to a Linux computer, determine USB vendor and product IDs using `lsusb`, then search for drivers matching this device.

A likely match is the `usbtouchscreen` kernel module (if you are building the kernel yourself, you need to enable `INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN` and `TOUCHSCREEN_USB_COMPOSITE` options, and then select at least one subdriver, for TouchKit this should be `TOUCHSCREEN_USB_EGALAX`). For X11 you will need the `xf86-input-evtouch` package.